# Deserialize JSON googlemap distance matrix in D365 X++ --

Tags: matrix, distance, x++

GoogledistanceMatrix distance matrix API output

I am using FormJsonSerializer::deserializeObject D365 x++ , classes to deserialize, however i am facing challenge to deserialize  below part -->
"elements": `

i created data contracts , but cant get through the above

below contract does not seem to work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxljM.png)

expecting to get the value of Distance .

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange all the Data Contracts hierarchically. Also you have to process every value that is sent to you in the JSON.

In your case this would be:

```
// Root Data Contract
[DataContract]
public class yourClassRoot
{

DestinationAdresses destinationAdresses;
OriginAdresses originAdresses;
List rows;
Status status;

//[DataMember("destinationAdresses")]

// ... and so on.  

//[DataMember("rows"), DataCollection(Types::Class, classStr(RowsContract))]

}



// Next Data Contract

[DataContract]
public class RowsContract

{

// Attributes


// Data Members

}
```